# Parse string and make array from values

Tags: javascript

I have a string "Color of model: White/White/White". I want to find out, how to get all colors(White,White,White) without 'slashes' and make array from this values.Quantity of colors can change (White/Green/Yellow/Black etc)

Comment: You'll get a better answer if you tag this with which language you are interested in.

Comment: @maess i don't get your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
let colors = 'Red/White/Blue'

console.log(colors.split('/'))
```

If you need to include `Color of model:` you will need to split twice, once on the `:` and then on the second array parameter.

```js
let colors = 'Color of model: Red/White/Blue/Green/Purple/Black'

console.log(colors.split(/:\s+/, 2)[1].split('/'))
```

Comment: Based on his example: "Color of model: White/White/White" you need an additional first split on ':'

Comment: I wasn't sure that `Color of model: ` was part of the string... I'll fix

Answer (score 2):

May be you can do the following by using [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var str = "Color of model: White/White/White";
var color = str.split(':')[1].split('/').join(',');
console.log(color);
```